# HTML + FOREACH - present data

Tags: php, html, css

i have for example:

```
<?php $array = array(aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii,jjj,kkk,lll,mmm,nnn, 111,222,333); ?>
```

and if i use foreach:

```
foreach($array as $a){
  echo $a . '<br />';
}
```

this show me data:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
...
111
222
333
```

but i would like set max positions in height - and if for example data is too long then this should be in new column:

```
aaa eee ... 111
bbb fff ... 222
ccc ... ... 333
```

How is the best way for this? I can use DIV or TABLE.

Comment: Your example isn't valid PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a counter in your php, where it creates a new `div` element for each three elements and float all the `div` elements to the left.

PHP:

```
$array = array("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","iii","jjj","kkk","lll","mmm","nnn", "111","222","333");

$index = 0;
foreach($array as $a){
  $index = $index + 1;
  if ($index % 3 === 1){
      echo '<div class="column">';
  }
  echo $a . '<br />';
  if ($index % 3 === 0){
      echo '</div>';
  }
}
if ($index % 3 !== 0){
      echo '</div>';
}
```

and in your CSS, you will need:

```
.column{
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can use [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you could use DIVS and set height and width in pixels. Test what works. If you're not satisfied with a height and width, you could also use javascript to count the characters.

Last but not least, you can add a counter to PHP and just add breaks or divs for a new column. Or you can wordwrap the lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example in javascript - http://jsfiddle.net/ZAWKq/ .

Use div and set fixed width for it, as I just did it in example above. In php it would be -

```
<div>
<?php 
foreach($array as $a){
   echo ' '.$a;
}
?>
</div>
```

Rest is left to CSS.

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants, he wants his container to have a fix height and a variable width. And data are appended below the other one, while creating a new column when it reaches the fourth line.

Comment: I showed you a php code below also :). Well basically as @Dan told, my example won't be correct. But you can use tables to set the values in columns or you can use more advanced DIV. Basically I would suggest that you would use tables for such features. With few another if statements you should be able to make it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
$max=3; //Maximum column 
echo "<table><tr>";
foreach($array as $a){

if($i%$max==0)
{
    echo '</tr><tr>';
}
echo '<td>'.$a.'</td>';
$i++;
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: OP don't want a fixed-number-of-column setup. He want a variable-column-&-Fixed-rows setup. Columns can be `n`, but Rows should be three, and any fourth, or seventh item should go on second or third column respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","iii","jjj","kkk","lll","mmm","nnn", "111","222","333");

$i=0;
    $maxRow=3; //Fixed row
    $col=(count($array)/$maxRow)+1;
    echo "<table><tr>";

    foreach($array as $a){

        if($i%$col==0)
        {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
        echo '<td>'.$a.'</td>';
      $i++;
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
```